# iOS 7 - hiding tabBar and showing toolBar instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitoolbar

I have a problem with hiding UITabBar. I have a custom tabBar which I hide using:

```
    self.frame = CGRectOffset(tabBarRect, 0, CGRectGetHeight(tabBarRect));
```

Instead of tabBar, I want to show toolBar. Everything looks fine, but I noticed the area that was previously occupied by tabBar is not responsive, although I offset the tabBar frame.

So, I just put toolBar as a subview of tabBar:

```
    toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(tbv.frame) - toolBar.intrinsicContentSize.height, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), toolBar.intrinsicContentSize.height); 
    [tbv addSubview:toolBar];
```

Unfortunately, my tabBar is bigger than toolBar, so I can't use this solution.
I know that I could add toolBar to appDelegate's keyWindow and on top of tabBar, but I'd like to place it within my viewController.

Is there any way to disable tabBar and use toolBar or any other control with gestures within current viewController that is part of navigation based app with tabBar?

Thank yee

Answer (score 0):

may you can try `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES;`

like this：

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES;//hide controller's tabbar

UIViewController *controller =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyRequirementParticipateInViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =NO;//when pushed back tabbar would show again.
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, but I need same viewController to be pushed with visible tabBar, and then, if user taps button, toolBar should substitute tabBar. And I rather not instantiate same viewController